# Trying to start JBoss using service jboss start - Not working

Tags: jboss, centos, jboss7.x

Trying to start JBOSS and getting the following error

```
[root@............]# service jboss start
Starting jboss-as: -bash:    /home/etsmart/softwares/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh: Permission denied
```

Even trying to start JBOSS using sh standalone.sh and getting the following outputJBoss Bootstrap Environment

```
JBOSS_HOME: /home/etsmart/softwares/jboss-as
JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/bin/java
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml
```

JBoss log:

```
11:33:17,973 INFO [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA 
11:33:18,076 INFO [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:33:18,107 INFO [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting 
11:33:18,555 INFO [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA > 
11:33:18,555 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http > management service     using socket-binding (management-http) 
11:33:18,562 > INFO [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA > 
11:33:18,569 INFO [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version > 3.2.3.GA 
11:33:18,581 INFO [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers 
11:33:18,582 INFO > [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) >     JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem 
11:33:18,604 INFO > [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) > JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem. 
11:33:18,608 INFO > [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408:     Starting > JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final) 
11:33:18,647 INFO > [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread > Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class > org.h2.Driver (version 1.3) 
11:33:18,656 INFO [org.jboss.as.security] > (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security > Subsystem 
11:33:18,657 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService > Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem > 
11:33:18,670 INFO [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- > 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem 11:33:18,671 INFO > [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) > JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension 
11:33:18,706 INFO > [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current > PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
11:33:18,706 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] > (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service > 
11:33:18,715 INFO [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread > 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default] > 
11:33:18,764 INFO > [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service > thread 1-7) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA > 
11:33:18,836 INFO [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC > service thread 1-5) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080 > 
11:33:18,984 INFO [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) > JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447 
11:33:18,984 INFO > [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening > on /127.0.0.1:9999 
11:33:18,985 INFO > [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) > JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory > /home/etsmart/softwares/jboss-as/standalone/deployments 
11:33:19,052 > INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service > thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source > [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] 
11:33:19,161 INFO [org.jboss.as] > (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on > http://-.0.0.1:9990 
11:33:19,161 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot > Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 1341ms - > Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand) >
```

Comment: which flavor of linux are you using? or try to give execute permission with chmod +x /home/etsmart/softwares/jboss-as that might solve your problem.

Comment: I am using Centos. It has got the execution permission for the file still its not working

Comment: Same mysterious problem here, did you get it resolved eventually?